# How to set title with UITabbarsystemitem

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbaritem

I just wanted to know how i can set a title of a tab bar item using `UITabBarSystemItem` ?

What i did :

> `self.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemFeatured tag:0];`

So to change the title by default instead of "Featured" (because of `UITabBarSystemItemFeatured` object), I wrote :

> `self.tabBarItem.title = @"Actu";`

So in my mind i should have "Actu" as title instead of "Featured".

But it changes nothing, the title keeps being "Featured" (default title).

I also tried :

> `[[self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0] setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Actu", @"Actu")];`

(because this tabbaritem is at index 0), but nothing changes.

Or maybe such a modification is not possible using `UITabBarSystemItem` objects ?

I hope this is well enough explained :/

PS : Sorry for my english and anything else wrong, 1st post ever… :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a `UITabBarItem` is initalized using `initWithTabBarSystemItem:tag:` you cannot change the image or title properties later on.

Source: [iOS Development Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITabBarItem/initWithTabBarSystemItem%3atag%3a)

Comment: Ok, so I have to import my own picture if I want to set the title. Thanks for the fast answer !

Answer (score 3):

You can use KVC.

`[self.tabBarItem.setValue("YourTitle", forKey: "internalTitle")];`

Answer (score 1):

You already wrote that:

> … such a modification is not possible using `UITabBarSystemItem` objects…

Those have `title` and `image` properties set to `nil`, so they have these values stored in some internal private properties.

Also the docs say:

> `-initWithTabBarSystemItem:tag:`
>   The title and image properties of the returned item cannot be changed later.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is possible, you can utilize method `_setInternalTitle:` from [private API.](https://github.com/JaviSoto/iOS10-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UITabBarItem.h)

```
[self.tabBarItem setValue:@"Categories" forKey:@"internalTitle"];
```

Precaution: use it only for test builds.

Comment: Awesome, this works. This is handy for using the system icons when rapid prototyping. Here's the code in Swift (works in Xcode 10 iOS 12): navigationController.tabBarItem.setValue("Hello", forKey: "internalTitle")

Answer (score -3):

I realize this is old, but perhaps this would help somebody else that wants to do this. Create a tabBarItem from the system item as indicated above. Then create another tabBarItem as if you had a custom icon and copy the image from the system item.

```
        UITabBarItem* systemItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemFeatured tag:0];
        UITabBarItem* theItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:theNameIWantToUse image:systemItem.image tag:0];
```

Comment: Yeah, my answer is incorrect I found out much later.

Comment: systemItem.title is nil as well.